# How to use SimpleDateFormat week number (w) and weekday (u) coherently?

Tags: google-apps-script, simpledateformat, week-number, weekday

I would like to set up a functionality for Google Sheets that provides a start and end day for a given week index number of the year. When using the Utilities.parseDate and Utilities.formatDate functions together with the 'w' and 'u' date format letters I ran into some unexpected behaviour where the 7th day of an indexed week actually precedes the 1st one.

Using Google Apps Script I'm trying to determine the first and last day of a week by week number.
Like this:

```
const firstWeekday = Utilities.formatDate(Utilities.parseDate("2023-6-1", "GMT", "yyyy-w-u"), "GMT", "MMMM dd.");
const lastWeekday = Utilities.formatDate(Utilities.parseDate("2023-6-7", "GMT", "yyyy-w-u"), "GMT", "MMMM dd.");
```

This gives: February 6 as firstWeekday and February 5 as lastWeekday. Some further poking around showed me that the numberings are clearly misaligned between the two formats. Printing out the days of February 2023 in such a week number - weekday number format gives:

```
1: 05-2
2: 05-3
3: 05-4
4: 05-5
5: 05-6
6: 06-7
7: 06-1
8: 06-2
9: 06-3
10: 06-4
11: 06-5
12: 06-6
13: 07-7
14: 07-1
15: 07-2
16: 07-3
17: 07-4
18: 07-5
19: 07-6
20: 08-7
21: 08-1
22: 08-2
23: 08-3
24: 08-4
25: 08-5
26: 08-6
27: 09-7
28: 09-1
```

Based on this I assume the two formats count weeks differently, e.g. the 7th week of year 2023 starts from 13 February for the week number 'w' format, but from 14 February for the weekday number 'u' format. Is this right? If yes, how to use the two formats in sync? There is an obvious workaround of counting weeks from the 7th weekday to the 6th instead of 1-7. But if my understanding is correct, what is the proper way of handling this?

Comment: Does Google Apps Script really use `SimpleDateFormat`?  That’s bad. `SimpleDateFormat` is a notorious troublemaker of a class, I am not surprised that it would behave like what you describe. I *am* surprised that Google had wanted to rely on it. If there is any way that instead you can use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, by all means do. You would then want to look into [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) and probably `WeekFields` and/or `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: What is your default locale? Week numbering depends in locale (European week numbers, Arab week numbers and US week numbers are all different).

Comment: Your results are disturbing indeed. Today is Wednesday February 8. If I read your output correctly, the line `8: 06-2` tells us that this is the 2nd day of the week. I can make no sense of regarding Wednesday as the second day of the week no matter which locale.

Comment: GAS does [use](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format) `SimpleDateFormat`. My locale is set to the United Kingdom

Comment: According to your link it uses the `SimpleDateFormat` specification, which is bad enough. I cannot reproduce your results, though. Using `new SimpleDateFormat("d: ww-u", Locale.UK)` I get `1: 05-3` and then `5: 05-7` and `6: 06-1`, which agrees with my understanding of UK weeks (week begins on Monday, and week 1 is the one containing the first Thursday of the year).